# Dealing with SELECT tags that have 10,000 options, page takes a full minute to load

Tags: java, html, performance, select, jstl

I have a simple web page that uses a select tag to let users choose items that are not in a database table.

The problem is that the number of options can sometimes hit 10,000 or more.

When the options get over 7,000, the page begins to load very slowly.  I'm using JSTL   to create each option right now.  I've tried to generate a large option string in the backend before handing it to the front end, but that didn't seem to help.

Does anyone else have to deal with large select tags?  How do you efficiently process them on the frontend?

Comment: For large datasets you have to use some sort of pagination.

Comment: You have another problem. Even if you improve your server-side to deal this 10K tags, you will have 10K `option` html tag in your client-side, which will cause severe slow-down for old browsers (and also for moderns). You'd better not to do that. Maybe you should imagine an HTML ajax pop-in showing the 100 first results with a pagination.

Comment: As you have a lot of options, so you should not load that with every request. Better to load them once and store them on application scope.

Comment: You need a different approach. A menu with 10,000 options does not make sense, quite independently of the technical efficiency issues.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, this is just as big of a GUI design issue as a coding issue.

My first thought would be to put the data into tree form so the user could drill down by category.  This type of problem screams "Ajax" to me because that way you could load only the top level categories.  When the user selects one of those categories you do an Ajax call to get the appropriate sub category data and then refresh only that one part of the page.

We had a similar problem at my old job.  We had one customer with over 2500 locations.  The drop down box of locations was too difficult for the user to navigate.  10,000 would be really frustrating.  We went to an Ajax based tree control. I don't remember which JQuery tree control we used but our solution ended up grouping by state and occasionally a sub region (Northern Calif, Southern Calif).